# Sending Received SMS using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sms

Hi there i have a fully running SMS application which performs 2 way process of sending and receiving. I am now on the part of Sending the Received SMS.
I will just assure that I am receiving SMS so ill just show the codes of the splitting part.

```
        'Split parts of the Message Received by "_"
    Dim textmess As String() = Message.Split("_")
    Dim pass As String = textmess(0)
    Dim txt As String = textmess(1)
    Dim recipients As String = textmess(2)
```

There i used the split function to cut the message into 3 parts. If the message says "abc_123_432" then the pass,txt,recipients would have abc,123,432 respectively but separated.

```
            'Verify Number for Authorization
    myr.Close()
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = "Select MobileNum,Name,UserName,Password,Position from tbl_user where MobileNum='" & Number1 & "'"
    myr = mycom.ExecuteReader()
    If myr.Read Then
        Dim num As String = myr(0).ToString
        Dim name As String = myr(1).ToString
        Dim user As String = myr(2).ToString
        Dim pass2 As String = myr(3).ToString
        Dim post As String = myr(4).ToString

        If num = Number1 Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Insert into tbl_inbox(message,received_date,sender) values ('" & Message & "','" & DateAndTime.Now.ToString & "','" & name & "');"
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
```

I would just want to specify that when i sent SMS to my application, it surpasses this part because when i checked my inbox table, it shows the right message which I've sent. On the following codes I didnt know where it went wrong there.

```
If pass2 = pass1 Then
                mycom.CommandText = "Insert into tbl_activity(UserName,Activity,CDate) values ('" & user & "','Send SMS to System','" & DateAndTime.Now.ToString & "');"
                myr = mycom.ExecuteReader

                Form1.txtnumber.Text = recipients
                Form1.txtmessage.Text = txt
                Form1.btnSend.PerformClick()

            Else
                MessageBox.Show(pass1)
                MessageBox.Show(txt)
                MessageBox.Show(recipients)
            End If

        End If
        End If
        myr.Close()
    End If
```

I also tried to make the pass1 and pass2 appear in a messagebox before comparing, but still it wont pass through even though they are exactly thesame. Please help me guys, i just need the needed code As Soon As Possible, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Dim textmess As String() = Message.Split("_")
```

to

```
 Dim textmess As String() = Split(Message,"_")
```

also why are you using = when comparing STRINGS???
Try this:

```
If pass2.equals(pass1) Then
```